# what does the command bash do when typed in a linux terminal?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, terminal

When I type `bash` in to linux cli, it gives me `bash-3.2$` so what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `bash` you are creating a new bash subshell within your current shell (even if your current shell was already bash), the `$SHLVL` environment variable will also be incremented within that new shell.

Comment: I realized that running `import subprocess; subprocess.call(['bash'])` starts a new bash subshell in your Python REPL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shell - think of it like the cmd window in Windows(if that's what you're used to). It allows you to execute commands. I would have a look through the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) entry as a starting point.